# How to configure Spring security Oauth 2.0 with dynamic URL matchers configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I need to implement dynamic spring security matchers (URLs, Methods, Roles, Authorities, etc.) verifications in a spring boot oauth 2.0 resource server with a remote authorization server.

Is there any tips on how to do it, extracting these informations to a database?

So far I have found one small indication on how to proceed, creating a filter extending *DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource* and overriding the method *getAttributes(Object object)*, but I don't  know if this is the best way to do it.
https://github.com/sohamghosh/spring-security-dynamic-roles

Answer (score 4):

I did my solution using the idea indicated by the link I posted with my question. If anyone could give me tips about it I would appreciate.

First of all I wanted *Authorities* associated with *Users* only on my *Resource Server*, because my *Authorization Server* doesn't have everything and doesn't need to now my application business rules, roles and permissions. Besides, I wanted to store these *Authorities* in a database so I could manage it dynamically. So I created a custom **accessTokenConverter** to link to my *RemoteTokenServices* (that points to my Oauth 2.0 *Authorization Server*) that overrides the method *extractAuthentication* of a **DefaultAccessTokenConverter** adding these new *Authorities*. See the complete class configuration below.

```
    /**
     * Class responsible for configuring Resource Server's security filters and connectivity with Heimdall (Authorization Server)  
     * @author mariane.vieira
     *
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class OAuth2ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Value("${auth.server.resourceId}") 
        private String resourceId;
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        @Autowired
        private DynamicAuthorityRepository authorityRepository; 
        @Autowired
        private UrlInterceptorRepository urlInterceptorRepository; 
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(resourceId).stateless(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                // Since we want the protected resources to be accessible in the UI as well we need 
                // session creation to be allowed (it's disabled by default in 2.0.6)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)           
            .and()
                .addFilter(filterSecurityInterceptor())
                //permitting all because security paths verifications are going to be dynamic
                //because of this filter above
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        }

        /**
         * Dynamic {@link AccessTokenConverter}, normaly extracts authentication just like 
         * {@link DefaultAccessTokenConverter} but fetches others authorities localy stored
         * with {@link DynamicAuthorityRepository} by username.
         *  
         * @author mariane.vieira
         *
         */
        public class DynamicAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {
            @Override
            public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
                OAuth2Authentication authentication = super.extractAuthentication(map);

                List<DynamicAuthority> dynamicAuthorities = authorityRepository.findByUsername(String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal()));

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                authorities.addAll(dynamicAuthorities.stream().map(auth -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getAuthority()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

                OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters(),
                        authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(), authorities, true,
                        authentication.getOAuth2Request().getScope(), authentication.getOAuth2Request().getResourceIds(),
                        null, null, null);

                return new OAuth2Authentication(request,
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), "N/A", authorities));
            }
        }
        /**
         * Instantiates Bean accessTokenConverter as an instance of {@link DynamicAccessTokenConverter} 
         * @return {@link DynamicAccessTokenConverter}
         */
        @Bean
        public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {        
            return new DynamicAccessTokenConverter();
        }

        /**
         * Instantiates Bean remoteTokenServices with informations of Heimdall (Authorization Server) instance and 
         * client credentials. Besides, sets our custom accessTokenConverter to fetch authorities dynamically.  
         * @param checkTokenUrl Url to Heimdall's (Authorization Server) check token endpoint
         * @param clientId Client Id registered in Heimdall (Authorization Server)
         * @param clientSecret Client Secret registered in Heimdall (Authorization Server)
         * @return {@link RemoteTokenServices} bean 
         */
        @Bean
        public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices(final @Value("${auth.server.url}") String checkTokenUrl,
                final @Value("${auth.server.clientId}") String clientId,
                final @Value("${auth.server.clientsecret}") String clientSecret) {
            final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
            remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenUrl);
            remoteTokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
            remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);      
            remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
            return remoteTokenServices;
        }

        /**
         * Instantiates Bean remoteTokenServices filterSecurityInterceptor, instance of {@link DynamicFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource}
         * that intercepts every request to verify security rules. These rules are stored in database and can be formed and verified 
         * dynamically. 
         * @return {@link FilterSecurityInterceptor} Bean, instance of {@link DynamicFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource} 
         */
        public FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor(){       
            DynamicFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource dynamicFilter = new DynamicFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(
                    new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>());
            dynamicFilter.setUrlInterceptorRepository(urlInterceptorRepository);        
            FilterSecurityInterceptor filter = new FilterSecurityInterceptor();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            filter.setAccessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager());
            filter.setSecurityMetadataSource(dynamicFilter);
            return filter;
        }

        /**
         * Instantiates Bean accessDecisionManager, instance of {@link UnanimousBased} with {@link ScopeVoter}, {@link RoleVoter} 
         * and {@link AuthenticatedVoter}.
         * @return {@link AccessDecisionManager} bean, instance of {@link UnanimousBased}
         */
        @Bean
        public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager(){
            return new UnanimousBased(Arrays.asList(new ScopeVoter(), new RoleVoter(), new AuthenticatedVoter()));
        }
    }
```

Besides, as described, I also wanted to verify security path access dynamically and storing it on database. I did it adding a *FilterSecurityInterceptor* with a security metadata source personalized by me. It is instantiated by the configuration class above. The class below is the security metadata source adapted to search in database for the paths and its *ConfigAttributes*.

```
public class DynamicFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource extends DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    private UrlInterceptorRepository urlInterceptorRepository;

    public DynamicFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> requestMap) {
        super(requestMap);
    }

    public UrlInterceptorRepository getUrlInterceptorRepository() {
        return urlInterceptorRepository;
    }

    public void setUrlInterceptorRepository(UrlInterceptorRepository urlInterceptorRepository) {
        this.urlInterceptorRepository = urlInterceptorRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@link ConfigAttribute} with specific attribute (access rule).
     * Possible values to getAttribute's return:
     *  - IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY - No token in the request
     *  - IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
     *  - IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY - With a valid token
     *  - SCOPE_<scope> - Token with a specific scope
     *  - ROLE_<role> - Token's user with specific role
     * @author mariane.vieira
     *
     */
    public class DynamicConfigAttribute implements ConfigAttribute {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1201502296417220314L;
        private String attribute;
        public DynamicConfigAttribute(String attribute) {
            this.attribute = attribute;
        }
        @Override
        public String getAttribute() {
            /* Possible values to getAttribute's return:
             * IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
             * IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, SCOPE_<scope>, ROLE_<role>
             */
            return this.attribute;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.attribute;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;
        String url = fi.getRequestUrl();
        String httpMethod = fi.getRequest().getMethod();

        if (url != null) {          
            //Searches for interceptors whose patterns matches the URL
            List<UrlInterceptor> interceptors = this.urlInterceptorRepository.findByUrl(url);           

            Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes = interceptors.stream()
                    //If the httpMethod is null is because it is valid for all methods 
                    .filter(in -> in.getHttpMethod() == null || in.getHttpMethod().equals(httpMethod))
                    .map(in -> new DynamicConfigAttribute(in.getAccess()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return configAttributes;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```